# How to check if pair (lat and lon) of coordinates is close to arterial road or highway on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, latitude-longitude

By "close" I mean 100m. Is there a way to do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) with your point as both the origin and the destination.  That will return the location of the closest road.

Calculate the distance from that point to your original point (using the [geometry library spherical](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) method computeDistanceBetween).

You may also need to reverse geocode the result from the directions service to see what "kind" of road it is, if it *has* to be an arterial road or highway, but you don't get a lot of options, you just get the closest road.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/docs/examples.html

The RouteBoxer class generates a set of LatLngBounds objects that are guaranteed to cover every point within a specified distance of a path, such as that generated for a route by the GDirections class. The primary use case for this class is to support implementing Search along a route against a Spatial db that supports bounding box queries.