# How do I select the subset of my lat/lon data that is highway travel using R?

Tags: r, google-maps, geocoding

I have some data which consists of time-stamped lat/lon pairs, a subset of which I've mapped out below using ggmap. If I wanted to select only the data consisting of travel along the highways, which you can kinda see on the map - the 280 running NW-SE between the green mountains and the grey flat area & the 101 cutting through the middle of the grey flat area (where the red is dense) - how would I select only that data?

[image: A plot of some time stamped position data]

What I'd ultimately like to achieve is a dataframe which contains only the highway/interstate travel. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280635/how-to-check-if-pair-lat-and-lon-of-coordinates-is-close-to-arterial-road-or-h), which is a brief sketch of a possible solution in javascript, & suggests to use the Directions API to return the nearest road for any given point. I could then filter those results, but I'm wondering if anyone has found a cleaner solution.

Here's some sample data ([CSV](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8z24wwu9zm5017v/sample.csv))

Here's the code to plot the above:

```
require(ggmap)
map<-get_googlemap(center="Palo Alto", zoom = 10)
ggmap(map) + geom_point(data = sample, aes(x = lon, y = lat),size = 3, color = "red")
```

You don't need an API key to run the above.

Comment: Reverse geocoding points which appear to be on the highways is frequently giving me nearby roads, so the strategy of reverse geocoding all the points and filtering by highway won't work too well.

Comment: Could you do a whitelist of known highways & use it to filter? Maybe you received multiple entries for each coordinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this post and thought this is an interesting question. I wanted to download your sample data file. Unfortunately, the link was not working any more. Therefore, I could not try the whole process I had in my mind. However, I believe the following will let you move forward if you still try to do this task.

I recently noticed that [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/roads/) offers road data. That is, you can get long and lat for the roads in the US, for example. If you can compare lon/lat in your data set and lon/lat of the road data, and identify matches in data points, you can get the data you want. My concern is to what extent your data points are accurate. If lon/lat perfectly stays on the road you are interested in, you will be OK. But if there are some margins, you may have to think how you can filter your data.

What I would like to leave here is evidence that the road data and googlemap match pretty well. As long as I see the output, the road data is reliable. You can subset your data using the road data. Here is my code.

```
### Step 1: shapefile becomes SpatialLinesDataFrame.

foo <- readShapeLines("ne_10m_roads_north_america.shp")


### Step 2: If necessary, subset data before I use fortify().
### dplyr does not work with SpatialLinesDataFrame at this point.

CA <- foo %>%
      subset(.,country == "United States" & state == "California")


### Step 3: I need to convert foo to data frame so that I can use the data
### with ggplot2.

ana <- fortify(CA)


### Step 4: Get a map using ggmap package

longitude <- c(-122.50, -121.85)
latitude <- c(37.15, 37.70)

map <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(longitude), lat = mean(latitude)),
               zoom = 12, source = "google",
               maptype = "satellite")


ggmap(map) + 
geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = ana)
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, because I still would have to figure out how to filter my data to include only those points which are within a certain distance of the road coordinates (about 50m accuracy in my data) but now I see that it can conceptually be done.

Comment: @WilliamGunn Thank you for your comment. what you need is to merge your data with road data and see how many point will remain after filtering. `dplyr` offers a couple of way of doing merge. You may want to give it a go. Alternatively, I am happy to try and see what will happen if you can upload a sample data.

Comment: A merge is a clever idea, but it will only handle exact matches, not matches within a certain distance of the road, correct?

Comment: @WilliamGunn Yeah, that is the challenge. If you can generate potential lon and lat values which covers this 50-m accuracy range, you have good chance, I think. This is like "near merge". This is like a bounty question to me.

Comment: OK, I might repost with a bounty if my attempt to just create a large matrix of lat-lon from the road data doesn't work. I imagine I could truncate a digit or two off the end of the road data to make it less precise and maybe get close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @WilliamGunn Your idea sounds pretty good. I was thinking something like regression line with upper and lower 95%CI. For each data point, you calculate how much lat changes when a data point going up north or going down south. But, creating all possible combinations of lon lat is better. Another issue I see is; what if two data points have identical lon/lat. If you just use lon/lat for merging, that may not work. I guess you need another column like ID in oder to keep the data points. If your matrix and data large, you may want to use `dplyr` or `data.table`.

Comment: @WilliamGunn I came up with another idea.This may be probably much easier. You want to create a polygon which will cover the +- 50m range. When you draw road, you have data points, right? From each point, you may want to calculate how many degrees you have to go north and south. Then, you can use `chill` to create a polygon. Once you have it, you can subset data points which stays in the polygon. In this way, you can avoid heavy calculation for a matrix.